# How to use wildcard in an xml file using powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$xml.selectnodes("/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER//TRANSFORMFIELD[@NAME='*_FG']")
```

I want it to return the all nodes where the attribute is ending with "_FG". But it doesn't seem to work if i write the entire name ([@NAME='AKG_PP_GY_FG']) it returns the node. Why is wildcard not working in this situation???

Answer (score 2):

You could try `$=` or `ends-with()`, but since you are using PowerShell this will probably not work, because PowerShell still uses XPath 1.0:

**XPath 2.0, 3.0**

```
$xml.selectnodes("/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER//TRANSFORMFIELD[ends-with(@NAME,'_FG')]")
```

For XPath 1.0 (PowerShell) use:

**XPath 1.0**

```
$xml.selectnodes("/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER//TRANSFORMFIELD[substring(@NAME,string-length(@NAME) - string-length('_FG') + 1) = '_FG']")
```

When the `_FG` can appear anywhere in the string, you can use `contains()` which is also supported in XPath 1.0

Comment: $= is not working and i don't wan to use ends-with because sometimes the _DT  might appear in the start or the middle